# Business hours between two Series of Timestamps excluding weekends AND holidays

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, calendar, time-series

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this (sample):

```
data = { 
    'start': ['2018-10-29 18:48:46.697000',
              '2018-10-29 19:01:10.887000',
              '2018-10-22 17:42:24.467000'], 
    'end': ['2018-10-31 17:56:38.830000',
            '2018-11-27 09:31:39.967000',
            '2018-11-28 18:33:35.243000' ]   
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
```

My goal is to calculate the (US) business hours between `start` and `end`, excluding weekends and holidays. For that I am using the `CustomBusinessDay` functionality of `pandas` as follows:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

len(pd.bdate_range(start=df['start'][2], end=df['end'][2], freq=us_bd))
>> 26
```

This is correct in terms of **business days** (it does exclude weekends, and the holidays of Thanksgiving and Black Friday), but what I really want is the number of business hours between the two timestamps. So when I try the native `BH`:

```
len(pd.bdate_range(start=df['start'][2], end=df['end'][2], freq='BH'))
>> 216
```

which is incorrect, because it accounts for weekends, but **not** for the holidays. So, I have two questions:

1. How to calculate business hours between two timestamps correctly, taking both weekends and holidays into account by excluding them
2. How to propagate this calculation across the pandas Series in order to generate a new column in the DataFrame?

When I try something like:

```
df['diff'] = pd.bdate_range(start=df['start'], end=df['end'], freq='BH')
```

The result is:

> TypeError: Can not convert input [...] of type  to Timestamp

The error message also included the whole series in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `CustomBusinessHour` and `pd.date_range` instead of `pd.bdate_range`.

The number of hours for your second row should be 145 because endtime is `09:31:39.967`.

```
us_bh = CustomBusinessHour(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(pd.date_range(start=x.start, end=x.end, freq= us_bh)),axis=1)
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x.start, end=x.end, freq= us_bh),axis=1)
print(df)


    start                     end                  count                                               diff
0 2018-10-29 18:48:46.697 2018-10-31 17:56:38.830     16  DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-30 09:00:00', '2018-10...
1 2018-10-29 19:01:10.887 2018-11-27 09:31:39.967    145  DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-30 09:00:00', '2018-10...
2 2018-10-22 17:42:24.467 2018-11-28 18:33:35.243    200  DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-23 09:00:00', '2018-10...
```

And `diff` columns start business hour  will `'2018-10-29 09:00:00'` when you use `pd.bdate_range`.

```
us_bh = CustomBusinessHour(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(pd.bdate_range(start=x.start, end=x.end, freq= us_bh)),axis=1)
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.bdate_range(start=x.start, end=x.end, freq= us_bh),axis=1)
print(df)

                    start                     end  count                                               diff
0 2018-10-29 18:48:46.697 2018-10-31 17:56:38.830     16  DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-29 09:00:00', '2018-10...
1 2018-10-29 19:01:10.887 2018-11-27 09:31:39.967    152  DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-29 09:00:00', '2018-10...
2 2018-10-22 17:42:24.467 2018-11-28 18:33:35.243    200  DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-22 09:00:00', '2018-10...
```

Comment: So is `us_bh` equal to `CustomBusinessHour` or `CustomBusinessDay`? I think it must be the latter

Comment: @nvergos  I just made a mistake in my code. `us_bh` should be `CustomBusinessHour `. The question key is `pd.bdate_range` and `pd.date_range`. I have described in my answer and you can look my edit history.

Comment: @giser_yugang Good spot!

Comment: @nvergos  can you give me some idea ,how i can calculate exact hours diff b/w start date end date and exclude weekends and holidays ..i want to consider all hours in a day to be business hours except weekend hours....  i mean  from monday 00:01 to friday 23:59...(businesshours).  from above code i think we can only calculate hoursdiff in business hours range

Comment: Correction :    except weekends and Holidays

Comment: @Rahul You can try to add `start` and `end` in [`CustomBusinessHour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessHour.html) when you need monday 00:01 to friday 23:59.

Comment: Thanks @giser_yugang ,i fixed this ,what if  i want to give this start =07:00 end = 23:59 for mondays in b/w startdate and enddate