# Caluclating hours diff between two dates excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a spark app that can calculate the hours diff between two timestamps and will load the results in hive table.

I can able to read the data from csv and load into hive table, but I am looking for a function available in pandas or numpy or any module which can calculate the actual hours diff (exclude weekends and holidays)

```
+----------------+----------------+------#
|close_date      |open_date       |  case|
+----------------+----------------+------#
|2019-08-19 15:21|2019-08-05 15:54| 41311|
|2019-08-22 14:58|2019-08-21 16:25| 45569|
|2019-08-17 10:41|2019-08-13 18:45| 88438|
|2019-08-19 15:16|2019-06-18 12:13| 12224|
```

Trying to convert to pandas DF from spark df using toPandas and getting below error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o42.arrowEnabled. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method arrowEnabled([]) does not exist
```

Comment: For US holidays, there is a pandas library pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar, did you check that.  This will give number of holidays if any, between 2 days which you can ignore while calculating the hours i believe.  Will try to provide a sample code shortly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Business hours between two Series of Timestamps excluding weekends AND holidays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797891/business-hours-between-two-series-of-timestamps-excluding-weekends-and-holidays)

Comment: you just want a hour difference between two dates or a hour difference between two timestamp?

Comment: @vikrantrana this is fixed ,Thanks

Comment: can you post your fix as an answer here

Comment: Firstly i have converted Spark DF to pandas Dataframe and i have used pandas time series modules to exclude weekend hours and  holidays ..See code in post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701907/how-to-change-start-end-time-in-custombusinesshour-based-weekmask-is-equal-to-mo/57713079?noredirect=1#comment101914600_57713079

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701907/how-to-change-start-end-time-in-custombusinesshour-based-weekmask-is-equal-to-mo/57713079?noredirect=1#comment101914600_57713079

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do this with spark functions. Its just that timestamp datatype made it tricky.

Comment: @vikrantrana Can we do this in pyspark without Pandas ?

Comment: @Rahul.. I was trying to do with spark functions only and I had reached to some conclusions also. It's bit tricky with timestamp but yes with dates column it's possible. I think so. I may need to revisit my code again.

Comment: @vikrantrana Thanks