# Python pandas Calculate difference between 2 timestamp columns in a dataframe excluding weekends in seconds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, timestamp, timestampdiff

I have 2 columns with timestamp on them, I need the difference between them in seconds in a 3rd column , excluding weekends. How am I supposed to do this in Python/pandas?
I want it to exclude Saturday/Sunday from the timeline.
Ex - 
1 . Starts at Thursday/Friday and ends at Monday/Tuesday - Calculate duration only for the time it lied between Thursday/Friday and then directly Monday/Tuesday.
2 . If it starts on Saturday and ends on Monday - Calculate only for Monday.
3 . If ex.Starts on Friday and ends on Sunday, Calculate only for Friday.
4 . If starts and ends on Saturday and Sunday - result is 0 seconds

Comment: See if this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797891/business-hours-between-two-series-of-timestamps-excluding-weekends-and-holidays

Comment: I checked this, but it calculates in hours, so even a 4 second difference is rounded to 1hour here. Also this excludes holidays. I just need it to exclude weekends.

Answer (score 0):

First, Convert the timestamp in both the columns to [DateTime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) if not it's already in this format.

Second, find if the day is a weekend or a weekday and use [`total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method to find the diff in seconds in the following way:

```
def find_diff_in_secs(row):
    day_of_week = row["start"].weekday()

    if day_of_week<5:
        #          Find the diff in secs
        diff_in_secs =(row["end"]-row["start"]).total_seconds()
        return diff_in_secs
    else:
        return "NA"

df.apply(find_diff_in_secs)
```

Comment: thank you, but what if the start is Friday/thursday and end is Monday/tuesday. I will need it to calculate only working seconds and exclude saturday and sunday. Also if it starts on Saturday and ends on Monday, i still need it to calculate only the Monday seconds. If it stars on Friday and ends on Sunday too. I only need it to calculate for Friday

Comment: What is the start time and end time of a weekday?

Comment: it starts at 00:00:00 Monday to 23:59:59 friday